# "Log file" of date stamps due to changes in workbook

Tags: excel, vba, logging, date

I would like to keep track of the changes made in a workbook (DATA). The DATA-workbook are used by several people to share information. Different people fill out the workbook with their relevant informations which in the end are saved automatically. I would like to know how long time each step takes and copy those date stamps into another workbook (LOG), in that way I can see if somebody has forgot to fill out the workbook.

```
Info          Requestor     Me          Support 
b1001        Kevin         Anders      Support
              04-03-2011    05-03-2011  09-03-2011                
dd1001      Carl          Anders      Support
              05-03-2011    05-03-2011  07-03-2011
hahv500    Steve         Anders      Support
            07-03-2011
```

The data above are just a minor part of the DATA-workbook.

The code I'm looking for should open the LOG-workbook and copy in the data and date stamp when somebody has entered their informations..

The requestor e-mails the file to me and then I e-mail it to Support. I suppose that when the requestor e-mails me then row 2 and cell B3 are copied into the LOG-wookbook. When I e-mail it to Support then cell C3 are copied and paste into the LOG and when Support saves it cell D3 are copy/pasted.

I'm looking forward to get a simple answer since I'm not an Excel  wizzard.

Thanks,

Anders

---

Thanks for your answer. As far as I can see will that code pop up a message box, if the Target is changed, and I don't need that.

I have this for the first step. I don't know what to do with the next step. If I have to do some lookup... Help is appreciated!

```
    Dim FirstBlankCell As Range

ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=False, Scenarios:=False
Range("B7") = Now


Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("Log_destination")
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Workbooks(Range("Log_file_name").Value).Sheets(Range("2011").Value).Activate

Set FirstBlankCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
FirstBlankCell.Activate

ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A6:D6", "A7:B7").Copy
Workbooks(Range("Log_file_name").Value).Sheets(Range("2011").Value).Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
```

Comment: I apologies for the ugly code - I did my best :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an exatct solution, but you may try to use the WorkBook Events. For example use

```
Option Explicit 
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  MsgBox "the value was changed"
End Sub
```

and change the action which displays the message to some routine, which would update the LOG worksheet. Of course you may restrict it to work only to changes made on a specifict cells.

Hope it helps.